# Issue with owasp zap plugin in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, plugins, zap

While using owasp zap plugin in jenkins and building a freestyle project, it is asking to fill on various details like authentication, source details and project key. Can any body help me out with it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The ZAP Jenkins plugin is no longer supported and we do not recommemend that you use it. The recommended ways to automate ZAP are given on https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/automate/